# Read input from input file given in specified format in scala

Tags: scala

I am given a input file in following format 
(a,[b,c,d])
(b,[d,a])

How can format this input to get values in form

> key => List()

Following code is used to split lines on basis of space.

```
 val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
```

How to store this kind of formatted input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle this I started with multiple data elements with and without whitespace separation.

```
%> cat junk.txt
(a,[b,c,d,e]) (w,[x,y,z])
(q,[wert,cv])(xx,[aa])
```

Then I opened the file and split the input on every leading `(` paren without consuming the character.

```
val input = io.Source.fromFile("junk.txt")
                     .getLines()
                     .flatMap(_.split("(?=\\()"))
```

I also need a way to recognize the pattern I'm looking for.

```
val dataRE = "\\(([^,]+),\\[([^\\]]+)]".r.unanchored
```

Now to transform the data from `String`s to `Map`s.

```
input.collect{case dataRE(k,v) => k -> v.split(",").toList}.toMap
```

Result: `Map[String,List[String]]`

```
Map(a -> List(b, c, d, e), w -> List(x, y, z), q -> List(wert, cv), xx -> List(aa))
```

Comment: Your solution solved the problem. I didn't know we can apply Patterns for case matching in scala. :) @jwvh